# Adding a timestamp to a PDF corrupts the file

Tags: java, pdf, timestamp, itext, bouncycastle

I'm trying to add a timestamp to a PDF file using a TSA server but after the timestamp has been added Adobe Reader says that the document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed.

Test code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestTimestampApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestTimestampApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    TSAClient tsa = new TSAClientBouncyCastle("http://tsa.buenosaires.gob.ar/TSS/HttpTspServer");

    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("I:/output.pdf")) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("I:/input.pdf");
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);

        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        LtvTimestamp.timestamp(sap, tsa, "Atenea");
    }
}
```

}

I'm using these frameworks to do the timestamping:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.58</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.58</version>
    </dependency>
```

And when I open the output file I get this:

[image]

Any idea what the problem might be??

Output file example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5OSF4ESCy5gRU5xTXQxU2NEMmM/view?usp=sharing

Thanks,
Julián

Comment: Take a look at this sample... http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-5#888-c5_04_ltv.java

Comment: Please share a sample time stamped pdf.

Comment: @mkl added the example

Comment: @joelgeraci that example adds a timestamp to a signature that already exists in the PDF file, if I understand the code correctly. What I'm trying to achieve is to add a timestamp without a signature (which I'm starting to doubt if it's possible)

Comment: *"What I'm trying to achieve is to add a timestamp without a signature (which I'm starting to doubt it's possible"* - there is no specification that requires that a document timestamp is only allowed after a signature. The result merely does not match any baseline or extended PAdES profile, but those profiles are signature-centric anyways. In particular the result should not a claim of alteration or corruption.

Comment: In PDF time stamps *are* signatures. If I understand your request correctly, you want to add a signature that has timestamp data but no appearance. Typically these are added to the first page of the document and are 1 x 1 pixels and have no appearance so that they don't show up visually. I think that sample would get you most of the way there.

Comment: @joelgeraci *"In PDF time stamps are signatures"* - No, not exactly. Merely "treated as a digital signature in most respects". *"1 x 1 pixels"* - No, the width and height both usually are 0. (Only "a line width of 0 shall denote the thinnest line that can be rendered at device resolution: 1 device pixel wide." In other context 0 is 0.)

Comment: @mkl - Ok - I should have been more specific... the timestamp dictionary is stored in the value of a widget annotation of type "Sig". And I clearly need to catch up on the current implementation of the "Certify (Invisible Signature)"... there was a time when it was 1 x 1.

Comment: @joelgeraci actually I also regularly see cases without a widget definition, only the naked signature form field; and sometimes I see widget sizes of n x 0 or 0 x n which also is invisible.  A signature widget of 1x1, though, strictly speaking is not invisible, merely very small. ;)

Comment: @mkl - Well now you made me go back to read the spec instead of just looking at what Acrobat does. You are correct on all counts. That hasn't happened to me in decades. Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `MessageImprint` in the `TSTInfo` of the time stamp contains the correct hash value of the time stamped byte range. Thus, the problem must be something different.

##Extended Key Usage

The ASN.1 representation of the Extended Key Usage extension of the TSA certificate looks like this:

```
 951   49: . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
 953    3: . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER extKeyUsage (2 5 29 37)
         : . . . . . . . . . . (X.509 extension)
 958   42: . . . . . . . . . OCTET STRING, encapsulates {
 960   40: . . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
 962    8: . . . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . serverAuth (1 3 6 1 5 5 7 3 1)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . (PKIX key purpose)
 972    8: . . . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . codeSigning (1 3 6 1 5 5 7 3 3)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . (PKIX key purpose)
 982    8: . . . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . timeStamping (1 3 6 1 5 5 7 3 8)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . (PKIX key purpose)
 992    8: . . . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . ocspSigning (1 3 6 1 5 5 7 3 9)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . (PKIX key purpose)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . }
```

This in particular means that the certificate is marked for use in server authentication, code signing, time stamping, and OCSP signing. Furthermore, the extension is not marked critical.

RFC 3161, on the other hand, requires:

> ###2.3. Identification of the TSA

> The TSA MUST sign each time-stamp message with a key reserved
> specifically for that purpose.  A TSA MAY have distinct private keys,
> e.g., to accommodate different policies, different algorithms,
> different private key sizes or to increase the performance.  The
> corresponding certificate MUST contain only one instance of the
> extended key usage field extension as defined in [RFC2459] Section
> 4.2.1.13 with KeyPurposeID having value:

> id-kp-timeStamping.  This extension MUST be critical.

*([RFC 3161 section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3161#section-2.3))*

Thus, the certificate of that TSA must not be used to generate RFC 3161 time stamps, so all time stamps generated with it are not valid.